# django remove the Superuser status

Tags: django

How to remove the superuser status in creating an `admin user` in django admin?, I mean for example, I am `Staff status` and I have a permission to create another user, as a `Staff status admin` I don't want to see the `Superuser status` in creating user. please see the picture below

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            perm_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                           'groups', 'user_permissions')
        else:
            # modify these to suit the fields you want your
            # staff user to be able to edit
            perm_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff')

        return [(None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
                (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
                (('Permissions'), {'fields': perm_fields}),
                (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            perm_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                           'groups', 'user_permissions')
        else:
            # modify these to suit the fields you want your
            # staff user to be able to edit
            perm_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff')

        return [(None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
                (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
                (('Permissions'), {'fields': perm_fields}),
                (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')})]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```